# Logic Laws and Sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

> Is  $(A∩B)×C=(A×C)∩(B×C)$ true for all sets $A$, $B$ and $C$? If so, prove it. If not, give an example of sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ for which it is false.
>
> Use laws of logic to show that they do/do not have exactly the same elements?

Not really sure how to apply laws of logic to sets...

Comment: The laws of logic apply, in general, to statements. In the present situation, the relevant statements will say that something is (or is not) a member of a certain set.

Comment: It is true.  YOU prove it.  Show (x,y) in left hand side iff (x,y) in right hand side.

Comment: Isn't it False? 
Because if A={1}, B={2} and C={3}
A intersect B={ }    (empty set)
(A intersect B)x C={ }  product is empty b/c A intersect B is empty.
(AxC) intersect (BxC) ={1,3} intersect {2,3}={3}

Hence it is NOT true?
Someone please add if the statement could be true.

Comment: $A\times C = \{(1,3)\} ~\neq \{1,3\}\\B\times C = \{(2,3)\} ~\neq \{2,3\}$

Comment: Oh I see, thanks Graham!

Answer (score 1):

Definitions: $${X\cap Y:=\{z: z\in X\wedge z\in Y\}\\X\times Y := \{(x,y):x\in X\wedge y\in Y\}}$$ Alternatively (and equivalenetly)  $${\forall z~(z\in X\cap Y\leftrightarrow ( z\in X\wedge z\in Y))\\\forall x~\forall y~((x,y)\in X\times Y \leftrightarrow (x\in X\wedge y\in Y))}$$

So, your task is to use the laws of logic to demonstrate whether $(A\cap B)\times C$ and $(A\times C)\cap( B\times C)$ have *exactly* the same contents.

> $$\begin{align}(A\cap B)\times C &=\{(u,v): u\in (A\cap B)\wedge v\in C\} \\&~\ddots\\[3ex](A\times C)\cap( B\times C) &=\{(u,v): (u,v)\in (A\times C)\wedge (u,v)\in (B\times C)\} \\&~\ddots\end{align}$$

Comment: If I inserted the definition for A intersect B which is (z is an element of X and z is an element of Y) how would I simplify to show that LHS =RHS?

Comment: Can we define the same variables u and v across all sub-terms that will be substituted in? i.e A intersect B being defined as (u is an element of A and v is an element of B)?

Comment: The scope of the literal tokens, $u$ and $v$ is within each set constructor.  You may use distinct tokens if you wish, such as $(A\times C)\cap(B\times C)=\{(s,t):(s,t)\in (A\times C)\wedge (s,t)\in (B\times C)\}$, then show that the constructors' predicates are identical save for alpha-substitions of the literals.

Answer (score 0):

For sets $X$ and $Y$, $X=Y\iff \forall z.(z\in X\Leftrightarrow z\in Y)$. So the equation in your question holds if for all $z$, $$z\in (A\cap B)\times C\iff z\in(A\times C)\cap(B\times C)$$

This is the logical statement that you need to either prove or refute. You can use the defining equivalences of the set-theoretic operations, like $z\in A\cap B\iff z\in A\land z\in B$, to further reduce this. Eventually all set-theoretic constructions will be reduced away and you'll have a formula consisting only of propositions like $z\in A$ for an arbitrary set $A$. You can just treat those as atomic propositions and your question will be a propositional formula in terms of these atomic propositions. If you can prove the resulting propositional formula, then the original equation holds. If you can refute it, then you can actually use that refutation to build a counter-example, but it may be easier to just intuitively think up a counter-example, and then verify that it is indeed a counter-example.